# How to prevent Vue.js from triggering input event on elements after asyncData

Tags: asynchronous, events, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a problem. In my `asyncData` method I am receiving product data. A text input element containing name has an `@input` event listener, so when a name changes a request is sent to API to edit the product.

Unfortunately the `@input` event is being triggered after `asyncData` a returns name. So when I refresh the page, the request is always being sent. Is there any way to solve that problem?

In `asyncData` I get product name:

```
asyncData(context) {
    const slug = context.params.slug;

    return context.app.$axios.get(process.env.apiUrl + '/api/v1/features/' + slug)
        .then((response) => {
            const featureData = response.data.data;

            return {
                feature: {
                    name: featureData.name,
                }
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return context.redirect('/admin/features');
        })
}
```

And if I add a @input event listener on a element containing name:

```
<b-form-input @input="editFeature('name', feature.name, 'name')" 
              id="name" 
              type="text"
              v-model="feature.name"
              placeholder="Enter a name"
              required >
</b-form-input>
```

The `editFeature` method is always being triggered when I refresh the page. Because `asyncData` returns the name and therefore its value changes, the `@input` event is being triggered.

Comment: Please share a decent code example because this is too abstract right now.

Comment: @Stephan-v Any ideas?

Comment: It is necessary for `editFeature` to be called on every input change though or do you have a submit button? Another option would be to only display the input when the data from the XHR call has loaded. It would be really strange for a user to be editing an input and while typing, the `v-model` value could suddenly be populated by data from an AJAX request. There are plenty of ways to go about this but your initial setup looks really strange without context and bigger picture of it all.

Comment: @Stephan-v, well we decided that it is more comfortable for users, you don't need to press the button :) of course we added a debouce to that action, for me it's so annoying that the input event is being triggered when data is returned from asyncData